# Firebase Function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to follow Aaron Klasner's tutorial on Hackernoon to create a Medium feed in react.

In order to test locally I need to bypass the CORB that Medium is using to block local requests.

I built out a firebase function, but it's getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at strip (/user_code/index.js:18:37)
at Request.request [as _callback] (/user_code/index.js:19:25)
at self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Request.onRequestError (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:881:8)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:324:9)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
```

Here is the firebase function that I got from the tutorial:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var request = require('request');
exports.medium = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  if(!req.query.username) {
    return res.status(400).send('Error: You need to include query param ?username=@yourUsername');
  }
  const url = `https://medium.com/${req.query.username}/latest?format=json`;
  return request(url,(error, response, body) => {
    const prefix = `])}while(1);</x>`
    const strip = payload => payload.replace(prefix, ``)
    res.send(JSON.parse(strip(body)));
  });
})
```

Here is a link to the tutorial as well: https://hackernoon.com/import-your-medium-feed-into-react-ceadbaf785c7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error your getting is caused by the body being `undefined`, so try checking for error before sending back a response:

```
 return request(url,(error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.error('Failed to fetch data: ', error);
    }
    const prefix = '])}while(1);</x>';
    const strip = (payload) => payload.replace(prefix, '');
    res.send(JSON.parse(strip(body)));
  });
```

check the [request docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

Comment: Now I'm getting a second error stating: ReferenceError: err is not defined

Comment: sorry, i used err instead of error in the if statement, but i have updated the example

Comment: I figured it out. It's because my Firebase account didn't support outbound calls. I had to upgrade. Thanks for helping me troubleshoot!